# Beam direction algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we are given with a system of mirrors. Also we have a beam emitter and a beam receiver.
Then we should find the direction the emitter should emit in order the beam to reach the receiver through the shortest path.
How can that be accomplished effectively?

[image: the emitter and the receive in the system of mirrors]

The picture is just a sketch for example.

Comment: Really nice question, but lack of your efforts spoils it. Also angle will depend of mirrors dimensions and coordinates of emitter/receiver. How are they set?

Comment: quite hard, since there is an infinite amount of possibilities in the real world.

Comment: I don't think the algorithm can be generic enough to accommodate all kinds of possible configuration in this case.

Comment: When you omit refraction, you can mirror the real word geometry instead of the beam. Then the solution is simply finding the straight line from the emitter to the (nearest) receiver, which isn't blocked.

Comment: @AlmaDo, I did search the answer, but I've found nothing. Maybe I just don't know the correct terms about this topic. Anyway any of my naive algorithms are too complex to solve this challenge appropriately.
Receiver and emitter could be set as circles with certain radii, but for simplicity let's suppose they are just points.

Comment: The only good way for such tasks is the way of copying the mirrored space. Any other attempts are senseless, so he had to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simplified algorithm for rectangular grid would work by calculating the virtual position of the receiver in the next grid -- just as if you were playing pool and wanted to do an amazing bank shot.

```
     +---------+----------+---------+----------+
     | O                  |                    |
     |===>                |                <===|
     |     Real           |    Virtual copy    |
     |                    |                    |
     A---------+----------+---------+----------a
```

Here you want to shoot O to A, so you mirror the geometry of the pool in your mind and aim to the virtual pocket 'a'. This scenario can be repeated (infinitely) by mirroring the geometry over and over again both horizontally and vertically. At some point there should exists some virtual copy of the pocket/receiver a(n), which isn't blocked by anything.

Comment: Is there any way to work out the best way to mirror things or do you just have to trial and error your mirroring until you get lucky?

Comment: Nice solution, though I don't think it guarantees the shortest path...

Comment: The candidates A, a, a', a'' must be sorted by the euclidian distance. The first candidate that is reachable is the shortest path by definition (omitting refraction). The fact that the target 'A' is not actually a point, but an area makes the problem more complex. In this case, where width = 2*height, there are several candidates other than 'a' to be tried first -- all of them being below or above 'A'.

Comment: @RonTeller It guarantees. You should only compare lengths of all found lines and choose the shortest. And you needn't check further copy spaces when the distance to the image of receiver is larger that the found minimum.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen you should address your comments to the post, if the comment is not addressed to the author of the post. Or he won't see it. In THIS comment the addresation is excessful.